# Error No module named 'kivymd.app' while running app with KivyMD library

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm using **KivyMD 0.102.0** and it gave me an error when running the main.py file.

[image]

And I'm getting the error below.

[image: ss]

```
   Error:  No module named 'kivymd.app'
```

While running [this example code](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/wiki/Modules-Material-App)

Comment: Please, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** because you didn't provide any details nor a snippet of your code that requires kivymd.app.

Comment: This error comes because kivymd's team upload a new version of their examples that requires 'from kivymd.app import MDApp' instead of using 'theme_cls()'

Answer (score 7):

Module `kivymd.app` appeared after releasing **[KivyMD](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD) 0.102.0**. At this time (2019) you should install **KivyMD** from master branch of repository. Specify **KivyMD** repository link for pip:

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

This method is described in the [*Installation* section](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/README.md#installation).

---

After releasing **0.102.1** you will be able to install **KivyMD** using package name:

```sh
pip install kivymd
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `python` program requires the module/library, simply install it via `pip`:

```
python3 -m pip install kivymd
```

Comment: 0.102.1 isn't released yet